# undefined control sequence and a problem for compiling a table

Tags: tables, multirow

I need a help to show this figure correctly. Numbers are not on the center.

```
\begin{table}   
    \label{ch:a:3:4:2:5}
    \centering %\small
        \begin{tabular}{c*{5}{d[table-format=2.2]}}
            \toprule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{MVV}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{QP}} \\ \cmidrule(c){2-6}
            \textbf{Content} & {$20$} & {$26$} & {$32$} & {$38$} & {$44$} \\ \midrule
\texttt{BookArrival} &1.72\% &4.65\% &9.84\% &19.17\% 
&36.15\% \\
\texttt{Newspaper} &$3.00\%$ &$8.39\%$ &$18.31\%$  &$28.09\%$ &$41.61\%$\\ 
\texttt{ChampagneTower} &$4.13\%$ &$8.64\%$ &$14.51\%$ &$25.83\%$ 
&$39.26\%$\\ 
\texttt{Caf\'{e}} &$7.78\%$ &$18.28\%$ &$31.58\%$ &$47.49\%$ 
&$64.43\%$\\ 
\texttt{PoznanStreet} &$2.21\%$ &$7.37\%$ &$15.55\%$ &$32.48\%$ 
&$49.00\%$\\ 
\texttt{PoznanCarPark} &$2.22\%$ &$7.41\%$ &$16.01\%$ &$30.06\%$ 
&$50.78\%$\\ 
        \bottomrule             
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

## EDIT

[Copied from 'answer' below.]

```
\begin{table}
    \centering %\small
        \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.3]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
            \toprule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{MVV}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{QP}} \\ \cmidrule(c){2 - 6}
            \textbf{Content} & {$20$} & {$26$} & {$32$} & {$38$} & {$44$} \\ \midrule
\texttt{BookArrival} &1.72\% &4.65\% &9.84\% &19.17\% 
&36.15\% \\
\texttt{Newspaper} &3.00\% &8.39\% &18.31\%  &28.09\% &41.61\%\\ 
\texttt{ChampagneTower} &4.13\% &8.64\% &14.51\% &25.83\% 
&39.26\%\\ 
\texttt{Caf\'{e}} &7.78\% &18.28\% &31.58\% &47.49\% 
&64.43\%\\ 
\texttt{PoznanStreet} &2.21\% &7.37\% &15.55\% &32.48\% 
&49.00\%\\ 
\texttt{PoznanCarPark} &2.22\% &7.41\% &16.01\% &30.06\% 
&50.78\%\\ 
        \bottomrule             
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Please complete your code so that it is a compilable document. To format code as code indent by 4 spaces (easy way: highlight and press '{}' button). Also, the body of your question has nothing to do with the title. What is the connection exactly?

Comment: Numbers are not on the center of what?  We need to know the question before we can give an answer.

Comment: Please look at the output image

Comment: @Cagri To see what? And your code still doesn't compile. That is, neither of the examples you've posted - neither question nor 'answer' - can be used to reproduce that output, which we don't in any case have a clue what to do with. Sure, it is a mess. But beyond that...? What should be centred on what?

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your help. As you can see the output of the table in the picture. percentages are mixed with numbers. I would like to add some gap between each value. Also i got undefined control sequence error

Comment: And compilable code? What's undefined? Anybody's guess. We certainly can't reproduce the problem. Just create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and post it. We can't help you if you don't help us. We don't have your `.tex` file. All we have is what you tell us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I put together an (almost) MWE; it's not quite minimal, but it gives a good idea of what the whole table will look like.  And it compiles; neither of the code you posted would compile for me, and because it's not clear what packages you're loading (since there's no MWE) I couldn't make sense of your table specification.

I started by greatly simplifying the `\begin{tabular}` line; also, your `\cmidrule` was throwing an error, so I changed `(c)` to `(lr)`.  This gives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}   
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
\textbf{MVV} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{QP}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6}
\textbf{Content} & {$20$} & {$26$} & {$32$} & {$38$} & {$44$} \\
\midrule
\texttt{BookArrival} &1.72\% &4.65\% &9.84\% &19.17\% 
&36.15\% \\
\texttt{Newspaper} &$3.00\%$ &$8.39\%$ &$18.31\%$  &$28.09\%$ &$41.61\%$\\ 
\texttt{ChampagneTower} &$4.13\%$ &$8.64\%$ &$14.51\%$ &$25.83\%$ 
&$39.26\%$\\ 
\texttt{Caf\'{e}} &$7.78\%$ &$18.28\%$ &$31.58\%$ &$47.49\%$ 
&$64.43\%$\\ 
\texttt{PoznanStreet} &$2.21\%$ &$7.37\%$ &$15.55\%$ &$32.48\%$ 
&$49.00\%$\\ 
\texttt{PoznanCarPark} &$2.22\%$ &$7.41\%$ &$16.01\%$ &$30.06\%$ 
&$50.78\%$\\ 
        \bottomrule             
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

[image: Simplified table]

You'll notice that this already goes a long way to making the table look better.  If you want the decimal points to be aligned (as it seems you do), you only need slight adjustments, plus the inclusion of `dcolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}   
\begin{tabular}{ l *{5}{D{.}{.}{4}} }
\toprule
\textbf{MVV} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{QP}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6}
\textbf{Content} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$20$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$26$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$32$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$38$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$44$} \\
\midrule
\texttt{BookArrival} &1.72\% &4.65\% &9.84\% &19.17\% 
&36.15\% \\
\texttt{Newspaper} &3.00\% &8.39\% &18.31\%  &28.09\% &41.61\%\\ 
\texttt{ChampagneTower} &4.13\% &8.64\% &14.51\% &25.83\% 
&39.26\%\\ 
\texttt{Caf\'{e}} &7.78\% &18.28\% &31.58\% &47.49\% 
&64.43\%\\ 
\texttt{PoznanStreet} &2.21\% &7.37\% &15.55\% &32.48\% 
&49.00\%\\ 
\texttt{PoznanCarPark} &2.22\% &7.41\% &16.01\% &30.06\% 
&50.78\%\\ 
        \bottomrule             
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(All the `multicolumn{1}` makes sure that those columns will be centered, which otherwise they won't be since their column specification asks that they be aligned on a decimal point.)  This gives:

[image: Centered on decimal point table]

Is this closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.. I am very thankful for you

Comment: I've taken the liberty of streamlining the code in your dcolumn-based example. Hope you're OK with the changes.

Comment: You said `your \cmidrule was throwing an error, so I changed (c) to (lr)` so how would `lr` solve the problem? I tried and it works but I still don't know why it works.